# Converting VBA Arrays to VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, excel, vba

I've been trying to create a VB.NET VTSO addin, where excel columns are rearranged depending on the column header value.

I found (online) VBA code that does exactly that, but Visual Basic does not recognise the "Dim v = ..." line.

Does anyone know how I can remedy this.

```
Dim v As Object, x As Object, findfield As Object
    Dim oCell As Excel.Range
    Dim iNum As Long

    Dim v = Array("First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number", "Address", "City", "State", "Postal (ZIP) Code", "Country")
    For x = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        findfield = v(x)
        iNum = iNum + 1

        oCell = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=findfield, LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not oCell.Column = iNum Then
            ThisApplication.ThisWorkbook.Columns(oCell.Column).Cut
            ThisApplication.ThisWorkbook.Columns(iNum).Insert(Shift:=Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight)
        End If
    Next x
```

Comment: `Dim v As String() = { "First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number", "Address", "City", "State", "Postal (ZIP) Code", "Country" }`.  [How to: Initialize Array in Variable in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim nailed it on the head with his comment on the fix.

```
    Dim v As String() = New String(9) {"First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number", "Address", "City", "State", "Postal (ZIP) Code", "Country"}
```

The [Array Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) is an Abstract Class, meaning you can't initialize it directly, but rather must do so through one of its children (another Class that inherits from it).  In .Net you must specify the underlying Type of an Array (Object counts too), typically by adding parenthesis after the Type in the variable declaration.

Comment: Thanks Guys! Worked perfectly!

Comment: ` New String(9) ` not needed.